# homework - combinatorics number of possibilties

Tags: combinatorics

We have 28 balls, 13 red and 15 blue.
What is the number of possibilities to split them to 3 cells when:

1) The number of balls in the first cell is exactly 12

AND

2) The number of red balls is not more then 4 in the third cell.

I thought that the solution is:

$ \sum_{i=0}^4 \binom {28-i} {12} \binom {13} {i} * 2^{16-i} \  $

Am I right?

Comment: Is having $x$ red balls in bin one different than having $x$ blue balls in bin one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that balls of the same color are indistinguishable. You appear to be treating all $28$ balls as distinguishable, which is almost certainly not what is intended.

Suppose that there are $b$ blue balls in the first cell; clearly there must be $12-b$ red balls, and $b$ can assume any value in $\{0,1,\ldots,12\}$, so there are $13$ possibilities for the contents of the first cell. Whichever possibility we have, there must be $16$ balls altogether in the second and third cells, $15-b$ of them blue and the remaining $16-(15-b)=b+1$ of them red.

If $b\le 2$ we have $b+2$ choices for the number of red balls in the third cell: it can be anything from $0$ through $b+1$. If $b\ge 3$, however, we have $5$ choices for the number of red balls in the third cell: it can be anything from $0$ through $4$. In any case we can have from $0$ through $15-b$ blue balls in the third cell, for a total of $16-b$ possible numbers of blue balls in the third cell. Thus, there are $(b+2)(16-b)$ possible choices for the contents of the third cell if $b\le 2$, and $5(16-b)$ otherwise.

Once the contents of the first and third cells are determined, the contents of the second cell are also determined. Thus, the total number of arrangements is

$$\sum_{b=0}^2(b+2)(16-b)+\sum_{b=3}^{12}5(16-b)\;,$$

and I leave it to you to simplify this further to get a numerical result.